How to specify correct kernel/initrd for PXE boot using syslinux and dnsmasq?
I have a dnsmasq server for DNS, DHCP, and TFTP for pxeboot. The DNS/DHCP options are working correctly, but my client complains that some files are missing when pxe booting. I assume I have something in my pxelinux.cfg/default wrong, but I'm not sure what.
My dnsmasq.conf:
no-resolv
no-poll
interface=enp5s0
dhcp-range=enp5s0,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.254,72h
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/opt/lib/pxe
listen-address=10.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
server=<upstream DNS server>

My pxelinux.cfg/default file:
default

label gentoo (squashfs/http)
    kernel /gentoo/kernel
    initrd /gentoo/network.igz
    append root=/dev/ram0 init=/linuxrc dokeymap looptype=squashfs loop=/image.squashfs  cdroot net.ifnames=0

File structure of /opt/lib/pxe:
├── gentoo
│   ├── kernel
│   └── network.igz
├── ISOs
│   └── admincd-amd64-20240721T164902Z.iso
├── ldlinux.c32
├── pxelinux.0
└── pxelinux.cfg
    └── default

Output of syslog:
Aug  3 23:50:31 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: error 0 TFTP Aborted received from 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:31 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: sent /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.0 to 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:31 yvonnel last message buffered 1 times
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: sent /opt/lib/pxe/ldlinux.c32 to 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/b84b89f6-9bab-48ea-a79c-0ca669694079 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/01-90-1b-0e-32-30-9a not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A000080 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A00008 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A0000 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A000 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A00 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A0 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0A not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/0 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: sent /opt/lib/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/default to 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/.c32 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/.img not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/.bss not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/.bin not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/.bs not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: file /opt/lib/pxe/.0 not found for 10.0.0.128
Aug  3 23:50:32 yvonnel dnsmasq-tftp[4405]: unsupported request from 10.0.0.128

I'm setting up the server to boot clients into the admin gentoo live CD which I extracted into components (kernel, rootfs, initrd) using the instructions here under the "Diskless install using PXE from the LiveCD" option.
